# SSH to a host with known but non-static (variable) IP

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

Is it possible to have `ssh` or `.ssh/config` use a dynamic IP address that is stored in a file?

I have a remote machine with dynamic DNS that puts its current IP in a file in a shared dropbox. I'd rather find its IP this way than use one of the dynamic DNS services.

Now I'd like to `ssh server` and have all the options and preferences from my `.ssh/config` file used. But since the IP is dynamic and cannot be stored in that config file, I'm not sure what to do. Can I access the IP and use it with `ProxyCommand`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

```
ProxyCommand "~/bin/connect-via-dropbox %h %p"
```

…where the `connect-via-dropbox` script would look up the IP address from your Dropbox, then connect to it using `nc`, `socat`, or `ncat`.

For example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
host=$1
port=$2

file="$HOME/Dropbox/Server IPs/$host.txt"
if [ ! -s "$file" ]; then
    echo "error: '$file' empty or not found" >&2; exit 1
fi

ip=$(< "$file")
exec nc -v "$ip" "$port"
#exec socat stdio "tcp:$ip:$port"
#exec ncat "$ip" "$port"
```

Comment: Selecting this even though I had issues getting it working. I'm actually using your comment to @Pavel and an alias. Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 3):

You can use backquote -->`<-- to substitute a command with its output 
Something like

```
ssh `cat file`
```

Comment: Yes, this works from the command line. And I can set an alias. But how do I get options in `.ssh/config` to work with this setup?

Comment: All options will work as usual, ssh command even does not know that the host name was output of cat instead of typed by you

Comment: @PavelBernshtam: That's sort of _the problem_ here – since `ssh` merely sees an IP address, and a _different_ IP address every time, it is a bit difficult to create a config section that would always match it.

Comment: A similar method that _would_ work, however, is `ssh myserver -o Hostname=$(cat file)`, which would apply options from the `Host myserver` section regardless of IP.